# Find name, department name and marks of top performer in software engineering

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

Write a query to display name, department name and marks of the top performer in software engineering.The solution has to be implemented in subqueries.
The expected result shows a single row.

I tried the below code

```
   select student_name, department_name,
    mark
   from student s, department d,
   (select max(value)
    from mark
    where subject_id=
                     ( select subject_id
                       from subject sb
                       where lower(subject_name)='software engineering')
    group by student_id
    )m1
    where s.department_id=d.department_id and
          s.student_id=m1.student_id
    order by department_name;
```

But this code gives an error at 12th line of invalid identifier in m1.student_id.

Please Help.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get

Comment: The error is because your subquery groups by student_id, but doesn't include that column in the select list - so it isn't visible outside the subquery. You are not the first to ask about this task today... wonder if your teachers check this site? *8-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add student_id in subquery:

```
select 
    student_name, department_name,
    mark    
from 
    student s, department d,    
    (select student_id,max(value)
     from mark
     where subject_id = (select subject_id
                         from subject sb
                         where lower(subject_name)='software engineering')
     group by student_id) m1
where 
    s.department_id = d.department_id 
    and s.student_id = m1.student_id
order by 
    department_name;
```

Comment: There is no student_id in subject table. It is in student table and mark table. Thus there is error in 8th line.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged